# How to include dynamic file as condition to rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

I need to filter messages with rsyslog according dynamic hostnames, which are stored in external file.

I would like to ask you, if it's possible something like this:

```
if ($msg contains 'for i in `cat /tmp/file`;do echo $i;done') then
{
action(type="omfile" file="/data/rsyslog/data.log")
}
```

list of hostnames in /tmp/file is changing constantly, therefore I cannot use static conditions in rsyslog conf file.

Many thanks in advance.